# Construction of an instance of Sequelize seems to take too long

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

I have some Typescript code that uses **sequelize@5.22.3** and **sequelize-typescript@1.1.0** libraries to manage an AWS Aurora MySQL RDS database (**5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2**).

This code is running as Lambda function which is accessed via an AWS API Gateway. All this (including the RDS DB) are deployed within a private VPC (the same one for all of them).

This is the function I call to create an instance of **Sequelize** (this is done on load time for the Lambda function):

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

function createSequelize(): Sequelize {
  const t0 = new Date().getTime();
  const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://aaa.cluster-c52mlmcfdpvd.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/bbb', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
    username: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      idle: 10000,
      acquire: 30000
    }
  });

  const t1 = new Date().getTime();

  console.log(t1 - t0);

  return sequelize;
}
```

**NOTE**: I have used dummy strings in the code above to hide sensitive data (e.g. **aaa**, **bbb**, **xxx**).

As you can see, I have put some timing code around this.

I am very surprised that it takes between **1.5s** and **2s** to do this.

This introduces an unacceptable latency in our applications whenever the Lambda is cold.

Is there anything I can do to reduce this time?

Other library versions that may be relevant:

- typescript@3.9.7
- mysql2@2.1.0
- aws-sdk@2.725.0
- aws-lambda@1.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked down the cause of this. The Lambda function is, by default, given **128MB** of memory.

When I increased this to **1600MB** then the construction of a **Sequelize** instance dropped down to around **150ms**.